# iostream not found

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am creating a catkin package that adds some .c and .cpp files to the library. The .c files come from some very old project and it can be built without ROS. When I try to catkinize the project, I dont want to modify these .c files but just add them to catkin library, together with other .cpp files.
However, some of the c files have #include, #include, and when I do catkin_make, it says iostream/iomanip no such file.
Is there a way of using catkin_make without changing any original c files.

Thanks,
Yiming

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192495/iostream-not-found/) by [Yiming.Yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/20176/yiming.yang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something was odd with those c files in the first place.
.c files are C files (i.e. not C++) and C does not have iostream, iomanip.

Therefore I assume that is actually C++ code. So renaming those files to .cpp should be safe and fix the problem.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2